# How to Fix "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in PHP

Tags: php, html, foreach

I am getting an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() while displaying array data into the HTML Table. please help me with this.

Below Error i am getting,
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mf/view_cart.php on line 56

```
<?php
   $bill= 0;
     $sno = 1;
   
   foreach($_SESSION as $products){
          //print_r($products);
   
   print "<tr>";    
   echo "<form action='edit_cart.php' method='post'>"; 
   if (!$products) $products = array();   
     foreach($products as $key =>$value){
var_dump($products);
   if($key == 0){   
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='name$key' class='form-control' value='".$value."'>";       
   echo "<td>".$value."</td>";   
      
   } else if($key == 1){  
   $p = $value;   
   echo "<input type='hidden' name='name$key' class='form-control' value='".$value."'>";        
    echo "<td>".$value."</td>";     
      
   }else if($key == 2){  
   $q = $value;   
   print "<td><input type='number' name='name$key' class='form-control col-xl-4 text-center' min='1' value='".$value."'></td>";     
   $bill = ($p * $q);
   echo "<td>".($bill)."</td>";
               echo "<td><input type='submit' name='event' value='Update' class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'></td>";
   echo "<td><input type='submit' name='event' value='Delete' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'></td>";   
   }
   
        
     }
   
   echo "</form>"; 
   print "</tr>"; 
   }
    
   print "</table>";
   print "</div>";         
   ?>
```

```
var_dump($products); Output.
    
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Shirt" [1]=> string(4) "1000" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(14) "coconut-1.jpeg" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Shirt" [1]=> string(4) "1000" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(14) "coconut-1.jpeg" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Shirt" [1]=> string(4) "1000" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(14) "coconut-1.jpeg" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Shirt" [1]=> string(4) "1000" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(14) "coconut-1.jpeg" }
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "Shirt" [1]=> string(4) "1000" [2]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(14) "coconut-1.jpeg" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "All in One Set" [1]=> string(3) "140" [2]=> string(1) "4" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "All in One Set" [1]=> string(3) "140" [2]=> string(1) "4" }
array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "All in One Set" [1]=> string(3) "140" [2]=> string(1) "4" }
```

[image: Screenshot of the Image]

Comment: This usually means that the argument (array / object) you supplied for arg 1 of the foreach loop is not an array or a object. I would var_dump the argument in that loop so you can see what is being passed to the loop.

Comment: Which one is line 56? You might want to fix your HTML, missing a starting `<table>`,  `<form>`'s not allowed in `<tr>`, surround your table with your form or place it inside a `<td>`. Also redundant `</div>` at then end

Comment: Not your current issue but the formatting of this code is doing to be difficult to debug in the future. Try https://3v4l.org/SBDRU, also not sure why you interchange `echo`s and `print`. `var_dump($products)` is needed to be able to assist you.

Comment: Sir Added var_dump($products); Output pleae help me

Comment: Line 56 is   foreach($products as $key =>$value)

Comment: Move the `var_dump($products);` up above the `foreach` (one line up). If it is of an invalid type for the `foreach`, it will spit out that warning but it won't enter the loop (since it can't be iterated) so it won't actually run the code inside the `foreach` (which is why your `var_dump()` now only shows valid values)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using the $_SESSION object for more than just products - maybe there is some user information in there.  I would suggest moving all your products to say, `$_SESSION['products']`